# Dynamic content and loading of JQuery scripts several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, cross-domain

I am having a page that loads content dynamically. Depending on which menu item the user clicks, different tables are dynamically loaded and presented using jquery.

One column of each table is having an update linke used to update the content that specific row is representing. When clicking that link a JQuery UI Modal Dialog is presented with a form loaded from a server in which the user should update the content and post back.

This is how I understand it, please correct me if I am wrong. I need to load the jquery script at the same time as I load the dynamic content in order to bind the events between the javascript functions and the elements that is being loaded.

Assuming my assumption is correct I do load the content and the same JQuery UI Dialog scripts each time the user selects a different table. I load the content and jquery files from different javascript functions loaded together with the main index file.

The consequence is unpredictable behaviour (probably predictable using the same use case). When loading the table more than once and updating something so the modal dialog is presented, the dialog is not presented anymore after the first or second usage, as one example.

Could it be a problem that the jquery script is loaded more than once? If it is, what's the principle or patterna I should use for this kind of application. If all above is false assumption, still, what's the principle or patterns for designing this kind of solution where different kind of dynamic content is loaded at several places (all presented within the same index file) and all need the same jquery files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking how to bind events on dynamically generated content.  You do not, in fact, have to load new script at the same time as new content in order to be able to hook events to said content.

What you want is the [jQuery 'live'](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler.  You can specify the target of the binding using standard jQuery selectors.  However, instead of the following syntax:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){ });
```

You would use

```
$('.foo').live('click', (function(){ });
```

The way this works is through event bubbling, where an event invoked on a child element (such as an input box) 'bubbles' up through all parent nodes.  In this case, jQuery just watches the whole document for event bubbles, and then matches it against your specific selector conditions.

Comment: Ok, I made sure I only load the jquiery ui scripts only once. Now, there's actually no difference. Actually, to some extent it is good because it proves that my assumptions are incorrect. It's ok to load them once only for all. I do already use .live... I think I have an idea what the other problem can be, but it's not related to this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look a jQuery $.live() and $.delegate():

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

These will allow you to bind events to dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about delegate. Is that new to the 1.6.x series (we're still on 1.4.x)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

1) Multiple tables with an update link on each rows to update their content.

2) Update button opens a modal box with a form.

3) Form is posted and data is retrieved after being processed by the server to feed the concerned table row.

If the flow described above is correct, I don't see why you should load jQuery or jQuery ui more than once.

You should do something like

1) Load the page with all the scripts required.

2) Set up and ajax call with the jquery .ajax() method ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

3) Use the ajax call to submit the form data to the server and retrieve the results

4) Use the success callback of .ajax() to feed the row with the updated data. Within the success method you should be able to retrieve the context (a.k.a. the link you clicked) and identify the actual row you clicked.

I hope I make sense.

If by any chance you need to create new rows then you should consider checking the .live() and .delegate() method of jQuery.

Good luck.